# How should be a Go GRPC server for this example client?

Tags: go, grpc

We are trying to simulate a GRPC service for testing purposes but we are getting problems with creating the server. Our client it's working with our GRPC provider and it is similar to the next code.

We are having the problem with the configuration of the server that receive requests with a nil 
as credentials.

---

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"

    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
    "google.golang.org/grpc/credentials"
    "google.golang.org/grpc"
    ecpb "google.golang.org/grpc/examples/features/proto/echo"
)

var addr = flag.String("addr", "localhost:50051", "the address to connect to")

func callUnaryEcho(client ecpb.EchoClient, message string) {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 10*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    resp, err := client.UnaryEcho(ctx, &ecpb.EchoRequest{Message: message})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("client.UnaryEcho(_) = _, %v: ", err)
    }
    fmt.Println("UnaryEcho: ", resp.Message)
}

func main() {

    flag.Parse()

    ctx := context.TODO()
    conn, err := grpc.DialContext(
        ctx,
        *addr,
        grpc.WithTransportCredentials(credentials.NewTLS(nil)),
    )

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("did not connect: %v", err)
    }
    defer conn.Close()

    rgc := ecpb.NewEchoClient(conn)

    callUnaryEcho(rgc, "hello world")
}
```

Comment: would be great to have the error.

Comment: We tried different things and get different errors. Some of then were: client.UnaryEcho(_) = _, rpc error: code = Unavailable desc = connection error: desc = "transport: authentication handshake failed: remote error: tls: internal error.

Comment: seems like TLS is configured wrong on the server ? Is the server code open source so we can check it out ?